# How to add numbers in Text file with Strings

Tags: python-3.x, string, text, sum

```
import csv

csv_file = 'Annual Budget.csv'
txt_file = 'annual_budget.txt'
with open(txt_file, 'w') as my_output_file:
with open(csv_file, 'r') as my_input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_input_file)
    for row in reader:
        my_output_file.write(" ".join(row)+'\n')
        data = []
with open(r'annual_budget.txt', 'r') as f:
 reader = csv.reader(f)
 header = next(reader) 
 for line in reader:
     rowdata = map(float, line)
     data.extend(rowdata)
 print(sum(data)/len(data))
```

Trying to add the numbers in a text file with strings but error is continually thrown.

Output:

```
data.extend(rowdata)

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Data Set:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xON30.png

Comment: Post an example data set. I'm sure this is a basic conversion issue but it will help write a good answer if you provide a data set to go with the example.

Comment: @Dave added picture of txt file for you

Comment: You're not providing enough error output to really be able to help you. Please paste your original csv, or at least a chunk of it, into a code block in your question. Also, please add the full error output rather than a redacted version of it. Full error output will include a Traceback, the line number, the command, and sometimes the exact data that caused the error. All of this is relevant.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You're treating space delimited text as csv which is not parsing correctly by the csv module.

At the time I worked this problem out for you, you had not provided origional csv data, so for this problem I assumed your csv file contained the following data, based on your screenshot of the txt file.

```
Annual Budget,Q2,Q4
100,450,20
600,765,50
500,380,79
800,480,455
1100,65,4320
```

Now, about the code.

You're defining `data = []` in a place where it is not only
not used, but also causing it to be reset to an empty
list with every loop through the file you're converting.

If we add a print statement directly under it we get this for output:

showing added print statement:

```
with open(txt_file, 'w') as my_output_file:
     with open(csv_file, 'r') as my_input_file:
         reader = csv.reader(my_input_file)
         for row in reader:
             my_output_file.write(" ".join(row)+'\n')
             data = []
             print(data)
```

Output:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Moving `data = []` to the top of the file prevents that.

Now with the second `with` statement and loops you're treating the txt file you just created as a csv file. csv data is comma delimited not space delimited. The csv reader isn't parsing the row correctly. if we add a print loop to check what is coming out of the map function we can see it's not doing what you're expecting it to, which is convert it to a list of floats.

Relevent code:

```
for line in reader:
    rowdata = map(float, line)
    for element in rowdata:
        print(element)
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    for element in rowdata:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '100 450 20'
```

There are multiple ways to solve the problem, but I think the best is to simply skip the whole first loop where you convert it to a space delimited file. Doing so we just depend on the csv module to do it's job.

example code:

```
import csv

data = []

with open('Annual Budget.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f) # Gets the reader
    header = next(reader) # advance the reader past the header.
    for line in reader:
        rowdata = map(float, line)

        for element in rowdata:
            print(element)
```

Output:

```
100.0
450.0
20.0
600.0
765.0
50.0
500.0
380.0
79.0
800.0
480.0
455.0
1100.0
65.0
4320.0
```

Now we'll add your last couple lines of code back in and remove the test code:

```
import csv

data = []

with open('Annual Budget.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f) # Gets the reader
    header = next(reader) # advance the reader past the header.
    for line in reader:
        rowdata = map(float, line)
        data.extend(rowdata)
    print(sum(data)/len(data))
```

Which now outputs:

```
677.6
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight Dave! I'm not sure of the problem now for I have replaced the code and still getting an error. After moving data = [] above the with statement and loops I still get "Value Error: cannot convert string to float" in relation to the data.extend(rowdata) line ...would an except value error statement work?